# Writing this constraint in gurobi?

Tags: optimization, constraints, python

I am trying to create this constraint:

[image]

using this code:

```
 for i in range(len(b)):
        for j in range(n):
            gm.addConstr(r <= (b[i] - a[j,i]*x)/ (np.linalg.norm(a[j])))
```

but keep getting answers that do not make sense. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You want one constraint per $i$, but your code generates one constraint per $(i,j)$ pair.

Comment: Do I need to recreate my variable a so that it is just a one-dimensional list?

Comment: You may want to try asking on https://or.stackexchange.com